# Probability and Expected Value as it approaches zero

Tags: statistics

I'm having issues understanding how to approach this question. Let $X_1, X_2, ... X_n$ be random variables in $(0,1)$ over some distribution.

Prove that the following are equivalent.

1. $\forall \epsilon, \delta \in (0,1), \exists n_0 \in N$ such that $\forall n\ge n_0, P[X_n > \epsilon] < \delta$
2. $\lim_{n\to\infty} E(X_n) = 0$

How can I even relate $P[X_n > \epsilon]$ to $E(X_n)$ if I can't assume anything about how the $X_n$s are distributed. Anything suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: With the current assumptions, this statement is false. Just take  $X_i=-1$ as a counterexample. I guess the $X_i$ are non-negative random variables?

Comment: My bad I guess we can assume $X_i \in (0,1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say that 
$$
E[X_{n}] = E[X_{n} \cdot I_{\{X_{n}> \varepsilon\}}] + E[X_{n} \cdot I_{\{X_{n} \leq \varepsilon\}}]
$$
where $I_{\{X_{n}> \varepsilon\}}$ and $I_{\{X_{n} \leq \varepsilon\}}$ are indicator functions.

Note then that
$$
E[X_{n}] \leq E[1 \cdot I_{\{X_{n} > \varepsilon\}}] + E[\varepsilon \cdot I_{\{X_{n} \leq \varepsilon\}}]
$$
and that the expected value of an indicator is a probability.

Comment: How are you getting the $E[\epsilon \cdot I_{\{X_n \le \epsilon\}}]$ part?

Comment: oh never mind. This is a great start thank you! Never thought to use indicator functions.

Comment: Indicator functions have always served me well! :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically this equivalence holds true, because in this case convergence in probability (statement 1) is induced by a metric, as previously shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533866/convergence-in-probability-induced-by-a-metric).

In particular this shows that (since in your case $1 \geq X_i \geq 0$):

$$ X_i \overset{p}{\to} 0 \Leftrightarrow E\left[\frac{X_i}{1+X_i}\right] \to 0$$

Now the left hand site is equivalent to your statement (1) by definition of convergence in probability, while the right hand side is equivalent to statement (2) since $0 \leq \frac{X_i}{1+X_i} \leq X_i \leq 2\frac{X_i}{1+X_i}$ (since $2\geq 1+X_i$).